# Multiple Queries on Same field in tables

Tags: php, mysql

Really hope someone can help me or at least point me in the right direction.  I working on a product site, that allows visitors to filter their results using a menu on side of the product results, similar to what www.asos.com have done.  Basically, they can chose product type, style,price,fit ... etc.  Each of these fiter types, have their own table and a reference table which links each value to the products table.  EG There is a

Products table with productkey and all other product information
Colours table, with the following fields, Colour_ID, Name 
Colourref table with productkey, Colour_ID

I'm using MySQL and PHP. I know how to query the database and display the data if the visitor makes one selection from each filter type and then to display the counts for each attribute, but I'd really like to be able to allow them to make multiple selections and then calculate the counts for each attribute, based on what's been selected. I've looked into how this should be done, and I've seen that subqueries are an option, but I'm concerned about how many subqueries I would need to create as I have 9 filter groups, that can have a large number of values. There are currently, 1/2 million products in the database, and this grow over time. I'm capturing the values that need to be queried via the url, so as an example

page=1&view=20&product=125,137,147&type=1,3,5&colour=3,9,5&material=187,345

As you can see from the example, I can have multiple values for each time.  I tried writing a query using AND. Example, product = 125 AND product = 137, but that doesn't work.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to go about doing this even if it's just a point in the right direction?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thank you in Advance

Vivien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you answered your own question already:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE   (product = 125 OR product = 137) AND  
        (colour = 3 OR colour = 8 OR colour = 5) ...
```

You need to use `OR` instead of `AND` if you want to select several products, colours and so on.
If you want both a product and colour then you need to combine those using `AND` in between. There is no need for subqueries here.

---

It's easier to use `IN` though:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE product IN (125, 137, 147) AND colour IN (3, 5, 8)
```

---

A more complete example of this SQL code:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Products p

LEFT JOIN Colourref cr
ON cr.productkey = p.productkey

LEFT JOIN Colours c
ON c.Colour_ID = cr.Colour_ID

WHERE 
    p.productkey IN (1, 2, 4)
    AND c.Colour_ID IN (1, 2)
```

This will select all products that have the ID 1, 2 or 4 which have the colours 1 or 2.

It left joins the required tables on the IDs and then filters the desired values.

Comment: Hi Christ,  just realised I already knew the answer, and was about to delete my question.  I was thinking of using AND's for some reason instead of IN's. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I have another question though, if you don't mind.  I've noticed that when I use IN in a query, MySQL doesn't use the indexes I have set up on the columns.  Does this then make these indexes redundant, should I remove them? Thanks again

Comment: @user1147635 if the optimizer decides not to use any indexes then usually because a full table scan is faster. Do all ID-columns have indexes? Please run an `ANALYZE TABLE <table>` on the tables and try again. How do you tell it doesn't use the indexes? However, do not remove them in any case. They might still be useful for other queries.

Comment: I did used EXPLAIN to see if the indexes were being used and the weren't whenever an IN as opposed to an ='s is used.

Comment: Also...  Sorry I just realised that I do need AND, with an example being, the user selects the black box, so the black id is returned to the url and is used in the select query to return values.  At this point in my side menu although black has been selected, I want to refine the results to show all the colours that are also associated with black. Not sure how to do this...

Comment: That depends on how much of the table is covered by the `IN`s. If you have for example only 10 entries and 5 `IN`s then a full table scan will be faster, so the optimizer does not use any indexes. If you have alot of entries in the table compared to the number of values you are looking for, and it still doesn't use the indexes then please open a new question with both the SQL command issued and the output from `EXPLAIN`. In general, indexes are definetly also used with `IN`s (and should be)

Comment: @user1147635 To the previous comment: If I understand it right then you want to select not only the black colour but also similar ones like grey? To do that, you will need an additional table that contains those colour relationships. If you need help with coding that, please consider opening a new question (with providing an example and preferably SQL code). I can't really help you in the comments with that ;)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want to do.  I'll raise another issue thanks